# AEM What Group membership is required for deleting a task via System user

Tags: permissions, task, aem

I am able to create tasks but while deleting task an Exception is thrown below is the error

`Error: Security Exception.  User [sample-service] does not have access to [deleteTask] for taskId [2021-06-27/bbn_-_approver1]`

Can anybody suggest the correct Group membership or permission required for deleting task

Answer (score 0):

If you trying to programmatically update workflow tasks, check if the service user has correct access to /var/workflow/instances

Comment: Yes that is my question, What permissions or Group Membership is required for deleting task ?